# How can I add a Foursquare-like Badge / Achievement Tab on FB Users' profiles

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, foursquare, social-gaming

I have already created a Game app in Facebook, and have posted achievements. So far so good...

The problem is that I now want to add a tab or block within users' profiles, **similar to how Foursquare does it (see attached image)**, but can't find documentation about it.

Does anyone know how should I do it?

*Note: I think I'm using FB's latest UI*

[image: example 1]

**UPDATE**: I've added Codecademy as another example [image: example2] .

Comment: I am wondering the same thing- how Facebook apps like Pinterest, Runtastic, Yelp, Instagram, Foursquare, Codecademy, and many more can post (text,pictures, videos) to specific Sections in MORE (via Drop-Down-Control) in user profile (not on page)?